# 3D model files & creating triangle meshes from it

Tags: c++, model, 3d, geometry, mesh

I'm new here. I'm learning C++ yet so I don't have a big knowledge about things ( well, I have a lot of experience with programming but with other languages. I also know how to work with a computer xD ). I decided to start working on a game engine. I know it ain't easy but that's one reason why I want to do it - trying/getting experience is the best way for me to learn.

So, I'm starting with the renderer but I have no idea how could I make a 3D model file which as it says in the name it would have a 3d model and it could be loaded into a triangle mesh in the C++ engine and I could use it with Direct3D. I don't want you to do anything except giving me an idea how to start.

Thank you very much if you decided to read this & help.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great question and rings so true because you are in exactly the same place that I was 3 years ago.  I looked around at various applications that I could use to generate 3D content.  I didn't want to spend time learning various applications because I wanted to get coding my game engine.  I couldn't find anything quick enough to learn to make it worth my while (that was free of charge) so in the end I put some scripts together to create the 3D models (vertex arrays).  These developed into a GUI driven interface which developed into my own fully functioning 3D Modelling Tool.  Now, after 3 years, my Game Engine is on the back burner and MeshCreator (check out http://www.MeshCreator.co.uk) is now my ongoing project.

You need a way of loading in Vertex arrays.  OBJ files (wavefront) are Text Based and fairly easy to read.  The output from MeshCreator is also ASCII based and there are details on the website on how to interpret the file format.

The File output from MeshCreator is designed for easy import into any 3D project.  You could also look at .OBJ files as they are supported by most 3D apps (including mine).  OBJ files can get a little complex though.

In short, you need an easy to use tool.  It took me 3 years to write my own so I wouldn't recommend it.  Try out MeshCreator, MilkShape 3D and maybe Google Shetchup.  Also, there are many sites that have royalty free 3D content that you can use in your projects and many are available in OBJ format.

Answer (score 1):

3D model file formats can be very complicated, mostly in the sheer amount of types of things they can contain (meshes, primitives, curved surfaces, materials, lighting, etc. etc.). Which also means that it can be very hard to come up with your own format too. So, there are really two options here: find off-the-shelf libraries to handle the loading of models; or, pick pre-existing formats and write your own code to load those files (and use a standard editor to create them).

The main problem with using an off-the-shelf library to load the models is often that these libraries are often intimately tied to a particular renderer and usually very complex in the (possible) data structures that are generated when loading the files. So, this is often a better solution only if you are prepared to adopt the renderer of which this model-loading-library is a part of or tied to. There are options like Irrlicht, Ogre3D, Coin3D, etc., which all have reasonable capabilities at loading fairly standard 3D model file formats.

If you are going to pick a pre-existing file format and create the loading code yourself (and thus, tied to your own renderer), then you should pick carefully. The 3ds file format is very widely used and its internal structure is nice and fairly simple, with the advantage that you can easily skip elements that you can't support yet (this is useful when you are incrementally writing your rendering code). Most other formats have similar features (forward and backward compatibility, and ability to skip "unsupported" elements). There are also important open-standard formats, vrml and x3d, that you might want to take a look at. Also, there are some simpler formats associated to some open-source 3D editors like [Blender](http://www.blender.org/). It is important to have a good 3D editor that can output in a file format that you can load. That's why you shouldn't create your own file format, because you will have a lot of extra work to do, either in creating custom "export" scripts (or plugins) for some 3D editor, or in creating your own editor (a monumental task).

Comment: As I already asked above, how about using RenderWare's DFF/RWX models as a base for my own model file type?

Comment: @user1807624 There are tons of file formats for 3D models. As I said, don't create your own (there is no point in doing that), pick one that is standard, easily created (i.e., with a good 3D editor, or found in online catalogues of models), and that has the kind of features you want. Many editors can also do the import-export / conversion work for you, so all you really need is to be able to load one format. DFF/RWX is one option (I don't know how good), but consider more standard formats like vrml, x3d, obj, 3ds, or blend. Look at file formats exported by Blender3D for a good list.

Comment: I just don't know which one would be better: 3DS or DFF(RWX)? ( I'm not considering .obj cuz I for some reason didn't like it ).

Comment: I guess what I'm going to do is giving ability for loading both.

Comment: @user1807624 how about collada? its widely supported and meant for this. Pain in teh ass to parse tough if you accept the entire profile.

Answer (score 0):

Search around. If you want to base your engine on DirectX, I believe the SDK comes with code samples explaining the basics, like loading meshes.

If you're just learning C++, I'd recommend you start with a much simpler project like making a simple game with an engine like [Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/) or [OGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/), but that's up to you.

Comment: I had the idea of starting by a simple game but that wasn't any interesting for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like [obj files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file). You can find online free files to play with. If you want to generate your own, I think you need some 3D rendering software. You can also search how to parse them and load their content in your programs.

Comment: How about RenderWare DFF/RWX models, I could use that as a base for my own model file.